# FactoExtra is only extracting the first 5 dimensions

Tags: r, pca, categorical-data, correspondence-analysis

I'm trying to use the `get_mca_ind()` function from `FactoExtra` to extract individual contributions to each dimension in an `MCA` (from `FactoMiner` package) so that I can use it in further analysis. Instead of getting info on all of the dimensions so I can decide how many I need (using i.e. the `scree plot` or some other threshold), I get only the first 5 Dimensions.

```r
#this should get indiv data (coordinates, contributions, and cos2) from an MCA into a new variable called Reduced. 

new <- get_mca_ind(MCA)

#I want to look at it to make sure i've got what I need 

summary(new$contrib)
```

and I get:

```
     Dim 1               Dim 2              Dim 3               Dim 4               Dim 5          
 Min.   :0.0000192   Min.   :0.000147   Min.   : 0.000009   Min.   : 0.000001   Min.   : 0.000001  
 1st Qu.:0.0482985   1st Qu.:0.057176   1st Qu.: 0.030022   1st Qu.: 0.029323   1st Qu.: 0.027998  
 Median :0.1935074   Median :0.245580   Median : 0.115066   Median : 0.116379   Median : 0.134186  
 Mean   :0.4081633   Mean   :0.408163   Mean   : 0.408163   Mean   : 0.408163   Mean   : 0.408163  
 3rd Qu.:0.6126128   3rd Qu.:0.562426   3rd Qu.: 0.325514   3rd Qu.: 0.366664   3rd Qu.: 0.433879  
 Max.   :3.0747167   Max.   :5.355167   Max.   :14.168752   Max.   :16.762048   Max.   :11.495243
```

from `new$contrib` I expect to get a matrix with one row for each individual and one column for each dimension-- 68. Instead, I get a matrix with one row for each individual and one column for each of only the first 5 dimensions.

Note: there's no tag for `mca` so I used `pca` -- `FactoExtra` has a similar function for `pca` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the number of dimensions to keep in the results using `ncp =` in the mca call (default is 5). See under "MCA" in the documentation: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FactoMineR/FactoMineR.pdf.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for. I kept looking through the docs and searching for info on FactoExtra and it didn't occur to me that the issue was upstream with FactoMiner. Thank you!